# The req.body is always {} when sending post data through fetch api to a controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, fetch-api, body-parser

I'm trying to handle all post requests in a controller, and all navigation from another controller. From the index.ejs file where the form is located, i've a text input and a submit button, I'm firing a fetch post request to same file ('/index');

my view looks like this :

```html
<form id='message'>
    <input type='text' id='message' placeholder='Type a Message' name="message" />
    <button id='send'>Send</button>
  </form>
```

on the submit button click, i'm firing a fetch request to post data to the same file, 
JS looks like this :

```js
btn.onclick = ()=>{
  var msg = document.getElementById('message').value;
  var data = {
    message : msg,
    sender : usr,
    time : new Date()
  }

  send_to_server(data);
  display_and_cache(data);
}

function send_to_server(msg_data){
  console.log(msg_data);
  fetch('/index',{
    method : 'POST',
    body  : msg_data,
    headers : new Headers({
      'Content-type' : 'application/json'
    })
  }).then(()=>{
    console.log('sent the post request');
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
    console.log('can\'t fetch');
  })
}
```

i've a controller defined to deal with the post request :

```js
module.exports = (app)=>{
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  var urlencoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false});
  var json = bodyParser.json();
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  // Control for message sending to the server.
  app.post('/index',(req,res)=>{
    console.log('request recieved');
    var resp = {
      status : 200,
      ok : true,
    }
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(resp);
  })
}
```

but, the req.body is always = {};
I've searched for solutions and tried most of them, but still i'm getting {};

Do i've to run every request through my app.js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>The JSON you’re trying to send is malformed; you need to add quotes around the key names:</s>

```
var data = {
  "message": msg,
  "sender": usr,
  "time": new Date()
}
```

Yeah sorry that’s wrong. I think you just need to use `JSON.stringify`:

```
body: JSON.stringify(msg_data)
```

Comment: it's still empty.

Comment: { message:
   { '0': { '0': {}, '1': {} },
     '1': {},
     message: { '0': {}, '1': {} } },
  sender: 'user',
  time: '2017-05-07T13:12:27.595Z' }
Visiting the home page  , The message text turned into gibberish?? But Atleast i got the response...  Now i'm feeling silly for that mistake.... BTW Thanks

Comment: now i'm not getting the message part, just the sender and the time.

Comment: I was gonna say, I think in what you feed to JSON.stringify you may also need to omit the commas between the members but I think actually maybe not that…

Comment: yep, JSON obj does have commas between props

Comment: I checked and found that the input field's value is undefined, that's what's causing the problem. i'll check on it.

Comment: Yeah, so I’m also confused now about why you’re not getting the sender and time

Comment: Aha, I see yeah OK

Comment: after stringifying, i was getting the time and sender, but now i've broken the code.not even getting the function called.. :)

Comment: ouch—well at least it seems like you got the fetch call constructed right at this point

Comment: yep, just forgot to update the page after changing the code ;0